# Using line tool in Sketchup 8 creates planes when I'm expecting just a line?

Tags: sketchup

[image]

The 2 intersecting planes are the result of drawing a line from a top vertex to a bottom vertex.
I am attempting to avoid these planes being drawn.
I only want the line.
When I select face style -> wireframe, the planes are not seen but are still there when another face style option is selected.

My current work around has been to go through and delete the sections of the planes.

Comment: The reason this happens is because you're closing rectangles or shapes. Just delete the plane if you don't want it.